# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number query not executed

Tags: servlet-3.0

In my code, query is not executed.

```
PreparedStatement ps1 =cn.prepareStatement("select 
   count(OperatorName),sum(Numberofbuses) from REDBUS_OPERATOR ");

 rs = ps1.executeQuery();

 while(rs.next())
  {
    int count_operators=rs.getInt(1); 
    int Nob=rs.getInt(2);
    }
```

Here is my table defination.

```
Name                 Null Type
```

---

```
TRAVELDIRECTORYNAMES      VARCHAR2(100)  
URL_LINKS                 VARCHAR2(100)  
OPERATORNAME              VARCHAR2(100)  
BUSTYPE                   VARCHAR2(100)  
NUMBEROFBUSES             VARCHAR2(2000) 
NUMBEROFROUTES            VARCHAR2(2000) 
ADDRESS                   VARCHAR2(4000)
```

this is my fields my table name is REDBUS_OPERATOR.

Comment: Please post the table definition for `REDBUS_OPERATOR`.

Comment: What happens when you run this query directly on Oracle?

Comment: my query is added please once check it

Comment: You can try converting the bus number column to a number before summing it.  Really you should be using a numeric column type to store numbers.